# Having a row of equally sized custom NSViews

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

I'm developing a custom NSView and I want a simple application to test how it behaves when initialized and when dealloced. For that I wanted to create a window with an Add and Remove button that would add my custom view, one next to each other, all equally sized. This is proving harder than I though. I had previous experiences with Qt and Gtk+ where this was trivial (as that's how you construct UIs there).

I tried creating an NSBox and adding them to it, but that means that I have to use auto layout and programatically create strings like "[view1]-[view2]-[view3]" which sounds like a pain and even then I'm not sure that's sufficient.

I also tried to use NSCollectienView but I couldn't figure out how to add arbitrary NSViews to it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `NSStackView`. It's a relatively new class found in the Interface Builder object library (second from right).

[image]

You can *stack* views vertically or horizontally and Cocoa takes care of all the auto-layout for you. In the snippet below I stack 30 text fields on top of one-another:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: NSStackView!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        for each in 0..<30 {
            var f = NSTextField()
            f.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            stackView.addView(f, inGravity:.Top)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want something a bit more sophisticated than the above, Apple provide a demo project called [InfoBarStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/InfoBarStackView/Introduction/Intro.html) to get you up and running. Whether it suits your particular requirements or not, this approach is definitely better than `NSBox` and `NSCollectionView` for the sort of thing you describe.

Comment: Can it have more than three children though? When I add a second one with the same gravity as the first one, it throws an error.

Comment: As far as I'm aware it can have as many children as you like (see updated answer) How are you adding to it, and what is the error?